# Render Component from sub directory

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I want to render a vue componet from sub directory. I am using laravel 9. I use Jetstream with vue and inertia. By default vue component shows from **Pages** Directory. I create another directory **Admin** and put dashboard component in **Admin** Directory. The problem is when rendering it's didn't show anything.

```
return Inertia::render('Admin/Dashboard');
```

I try to render this view. but it didn't show the result. Only show the componet when

return Inertia::render('Dashboard'); render without directory name. How to render a component like this Pages/Admin/Component.vue ?.
I use default configation that jetstream provide.

Comment: Maybe try with `./Admin/Dashboard`? Just a guess, never used Inertia before.

Comment: You could maybe check on Github or Discord too.

Comment: if in your filesystem you have a page-component in this path - `resources/js/Pages/Admin/Dashboard.vue` you have to do `return Inertia::render('Admin/Dashboard');`

Comment: @ericmp this looks like exactly what OP tried already haha.

Comment: and should work like that yeah (: maybe they could tell if they modified something and now it is crashed, you know